# HTML/JS app within an Android App

Tags: java, javascript, android, html

Im looking to create an application written in HTML/JS and wrapped within a Android App. The reason for this is that I need to access the device's components (such as the microphone and storage) but because of time restraints I do not have time to full learn Android development. I am fluent in HTML/JS so it would not take me very long to write the core of the application in these languages. My thought was to write the application in HTML/JS and use a webview within the Android app, then record sounds from the microphone using Java and send them to the HMTL/JS webview.

Can anyone tell me if this is possible and if so point me in the right direction of where to start. If not is there another way that I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/), they provide exactly what you want to create yourself.

Or one of a [list of similar solutions](http://alternativeto.net/software/phonegap/).